# BJT one stage amplifier with current source

Tags: amplifier, current-source, bias

How I can correct my schematic to properly set the current source in the emitter of BJT common emitter stage? I can't understand how to properly bias the Q1 using R3/R4 voltage divider. How to find values of that resistors if unpredictable resistance of current source exists in emitter of Q1. It seems to use the current source must stabilize Q1 emitter current but don't spawn new problems!

[image]

Comment: I can't imagine how a current source on the emitter would help anything.

Comment: The current source set the constant DC current through Q1 CE

Comment: But the AC gain for this circuit arrangement will be one or even less than one. So what is the point?

Comment: About what "point" do you ask?

Comment: Also, you have error in your circuit. And the point is --> this circuit do not have any voltage gain.

Comment: You have the current source wired backwards - Q2/Q3 base should connect to Q3 collector, not Q2 collector.

Comment: @G36 What is an error? Ok, if I don't have voltage gain how I can rearrange circuit to have some gain? This circuit is interesing for me because of there are different textbooks that tell good stories about how it's good to stabilize the CE current with current source and I'm trying to view that advantages using this schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrected circuits diagram looks like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIQHs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For CE amplifier \$R_L\$ >> \$R_C\$ Do you know why?

The \$Q_2\$ in the current mirror need some voltage "headroom" (\$Q_2\$  cannot be saturated). I Assumed 1V of a headroom.

Therefore \$Q_2\$  base voltage needs to be around \$1.7\textrm{V}\$. And \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ voltage divider do just that. The voltage divider current should be at least ten times larger the base current. Which is not the case here.

To get the maximum voltage swing I decided to pick the \$V_{Rc}\$ value as:

$$V_{Rc} = \frac{(V_{CC} - V_E)}{2} = \frac{10\textrm{V} - 1\textrm{V}}{2} = 4.5\textrm{V}$$

So, if \$R_C = 1\textrm{k}\Omega\$ we have : 
$$I_C = \frac{4.5\textrm{V}}{1\textrm{k}\Omega} = 4.5\textrm{mA} $$

\$R_3\$ resistor bias the current mirror and we need \$4.5\textrm{mA}\$.

$$R_3 = \frac{10\textrm{V} - 0.7\textrm{V}}{4.5\textrm{mA}}= 2\textrm{k}\Omega$$

Now we can choose the voltage divider resistors values. 
Since \$I_C = 4.5\textrm{mA}\$ and the \$\beta_{min} = 100\$ I decide to pick  the resistor values this way.

$$R_2 =\frac{V_B}{5\cdot I_B} =\frac{1.7V}{5\cdot \frac{4.5\textrm{mA}}{100} }= 7.5\textrm{k}\Omega$$

$$R_1 =\frac{V_{CC} - V_B}{6\cdot I_B} =\frac{8.3V}{6\cdot \frac{4.5\textrm{mA}}{100} }= 30\textrm{k}\Omega$$

Also, as you can see I add \$C_E\$ capacitor to increase the gain.

Without this additional capacitor, the voltage gain is very low. Why?

The CE stage gain is \$\Large\frac{R_C||R_L}{r_{e1}+r_{o2}}\$ where \$r_{o2}\$ is \$Q_2\$ output "resistance" seen from \$Q_2\$ collector into \$Q_2\$. And of because this gain is small. The\$r_{o2}\$ "resistance" is large so, the stage voltage gain will be very small.

By adding \$C_E\$ capacitor we are bypassing (shunt) this large output resistance by a very small \$X_C\$ capacitive reactance.

$$A_v = - \frac{R_C||R_L||r_{o1}}{r_{e1}} \cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta+1}$$

And now you can play with this circuit in your circuit simulator program.

Do you see any advantage of this topology?

Comment: R_L >> R_C because of load resistance must not to overload an amplifier, another way the Av grain of CE stage will be very small

Comment: I see that advantage that see all textbooks authors - now I have constant Q1 CE current which makes Q-point stable and hard-fixed on 1/2 of Vcc or it's not so?

Comment: Q2 1V headroom is fixed with R1/R2 divider in your circuit?

Comment: In circuit lab the DC analyzer show that Q1 emitter voltage is 222 nV. It must be near 1V I can't find where is trick!

Comment: Q2 cannot be saturated? I think that it must be so because of saturation case the mirrored current will be very big.

Comment: If this circuit do not have so much advantages to use it in practive why it always mentioned in different textbooks as a good solution (using current sources) of unstable Q-point?

Comment: Compare this circuit with a traditional CE amplifier. You can build one by simply remove Q2 form the circuit. And place a 240 Ohms emitter resistor in place of Q2. What is DC analyzer?? Show me a picture.

Comment: Here you can see that emitter of Q1 is 222 nv: https://ibb.co/eWeT0w

Comment: @MaxMil Ok I see, I forgot to add a GND symbol. But now I fix it.